# SAS add in for Excel inserts columns

Tags: excel, sas

I am trying to write some Excel formulas that reference cells in a frequently re-imported SAS add in table. The issue is that when the add in brings in a table, it inserts the columns instead of just adding data, so all relative references get shifted. (E.g. If I reference A2 for a 4-column SAS table, the formula changes to E2 if I delete the table and re-import with new filters). I can't use table references because the table name changes each time you import. Can't used named range for reason #1 above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to insert the data into the same sheet that has the formulas?  Keep the sheet that is being written by the import separate form the sheet you are editing manually in Excel.

Comment: No, I am not. One sheet with formulas. Other sheets with imported data. Formulas work fine. When I import a table, it does it as an "insert data" operation and changes all of the relative references on the formula sheet.

Comment: @pythonpythoff I suspect there's a better way to do what you're doing, but I don't have the add-in to verify that.  I would post this on communities.sas.com and see if you can get an answer there - we don't have too many SAS Add-in users here I don't think.